# Test that errors are thrown in use Effect hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that fetches data wrapped in a function to made async calls cancelable:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 const asyncRequest = makeCancelable(myService.asyncRequest());
 asyncRequest.promise
   .then((result) =>
      setState(result),
   )
   .catch((e) => {
      if (!e?.isCanceled) {
          //Case the rejection is not caused by a cancel request
          throw e;
      }
   });
 return () => {
   asyncRequest.cancel(); 
 };
},[])
```

I want to test that, when the rejection is not coming from a cancel request, the error is re-thrown (I'm filtering out cancel rejections since they are not true errors). So the goal is **intercept exceptions coming from useEffect**

How can I test it with enzyme and/or jest?

```
it('should not filter rejection not caused by cancel', () => {
  let promise = Promise.reject(new Error('Generic error'));
  when(myService.asyncRequest()).thenReturn(promise); // This will cause useEffect to throw
  const myComponent = mount(<MyComponent />) // How to intercept the error?
})
```

To give further context here is the code of `makeCancelable`:

```
export function makeCancelable<T>(promise: Promise<T>): CancelablePromise<T> {
  let isCanceled = false;

  const wrappedPromise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    promise.then(
      (val) => (isCanceled ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : resolve(val)),
      (error) => (isCanceled ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : reject(error)),
    );
  });

  return {
    promise: wrappedPromise,
    cancel() {
      isCanceled = true;
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: You can't test that. It's an unhandled promise rejection, you have no access to it from your test - where are you re throwing it _to_?

Comment: I'm only filtering cancel errors out. I'm not catching that error anymore since it is supposed to reach the console.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Additional note to the previous comment: the purpose of the test, if possible, should be verifying that, when the rejection is not caused by a cancel request, it is not filtered. So if possible I want to verify that other exceptions are left unhandled.

Comment: Again it's an _unhandled_ promise rejection. It doesn't currently go anywhere, there's no way to assert in the test it got thrown, and if you're using Jest in [Node 15+](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v15.0.0/#throw-on-unhandled-rejections-33021) it will just crash the Node process entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. I was explaining because I thought you didn't understood what I was trying to do. Is there a better approach than re-throwing all the exceptions to filter out my request that would make the code testable?